# Using set_index() for multindex got Keyerror

Tags: python, pandas

I want to Add Multindex in my data frame so, I use this script but when I run this I get Key error.

```
df.set_index(['X','Y','Z'],inplace=True)
```

when I try to set multi-index in the data frames I got **key error** 
key error:'X'
is there any way to resolve the issue.

Comment: If use `New_df=A.groupby(['X','Y','Z'])['a','b','c'].sum()` then get `MultiIndex` with `A,B, C`, so `.reset_Index()
New_df.set_index(['X','Y','Z'],inplace=True)` is not necessary

Comment: @jezrarl But other data frames to I got key error.

Comment: @jezrael i just change question and lets see again.

Comment: So `A.groupby(['X','Y','Z'])['a','b','c'].sum()` failed?

Comment: @jezrael no script no failed Actually when i try to multiindex a dataframe i got keyerror

Comment: there should be 2 problems, no `X` column because no exist in some dataframe or `X` is already in index, so cannot again set to index.

Comment: Check `df.columns` and `df.index.names` for problematic data